# How to store session in command line interface

Tags: go, command-line-interface, go-cobra

I am trying to design a command-line interface in Go based on the cobra package which mimics the functionalities available in the user interface. I am facing a problem when the user provides the initial credentials for login in one command and then he executes the next set of commands.
In this scenario, I either need to store credentials that are not safe to store or I would need to store the session object which I have created, but now sure how to store the session object as the program is not constantly running.

Comment: What is "the session object"? Can you show what you're talking about? Most likely it's a client struct, which you probably can't serialize/deserialize effectively. You'll need to store either some kind of session token, or the credentials themselves; either way, you're going to be creating a potential security issue by storing it on disk.

Comment: Yes, Your understanding is correct. But then what should be done in order to pass this session information to the next commands?

Answer (score -2):

you can use https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers

like in this example

```
p := NewShellProgramFunc("docker-credential-secretservice")

c := &credentials.Credentials{
    ServerURL: "https://example.com",
    Username:  "calavera",
    Secret:    "my super secret token",
}

if err := Store(p, c); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```